# GCFI Outlet Trips with no load or downstream connections

Tags: electrical, gfci

I have an outdoor outlet that stopped working (had a light on that showed it was tripped and wouldn't reset).

I bought a new one to replace it and hooked it up, but the new one also trips just after it is reset.

There's nothing plugged in and nothing downstream, so I'm not sure how this is possible.  The hot (black) is receiving power and it clicks in on reset.

Can something upstream cause the outlet to trip?
[image: New outlet hooked up]

[image: Hot side is receiving power]

Update: Here's the problem:[image]

Comment: It's a possible power quality issue, caused by big motor kicking-in and other big appliances, often is due to factories nearby. Here (Italy) we can have specific high-immunity RCD made to withstand disturbing currents, you may try one of these.

Comment: @DDS I have other GFCIs that don't have this issue - do you know of something that could cause it upstream on the circuit? It's after a bunch of electronics

Answer (score 1):

### It's dead, Jim

You have kept the tape on the LOAD terminals and nothing is plugged into it. That's a good a test as you can do.

Really the only thing left to do is test whether the power is good.  I would swap in a plain receptacle and plug in an appliance and see if the appliance works.  That will be a more definitive test than you can get from that probe.

Comment: I swapped it with a plain receptacle and plugged in a lamp - worked fine.  Checked the voltage, it's a little over 120v.  Plugging the lamp into the GFCI even turns on for the part of a second that the button is pressed before it trips off.

Comment: Solved it! I assumed the tape was correctly on the LOAD terminals, but it turns out it was on the line side.  Swapped that and it works fine

Comment: @kbickar -- that sounds like an answer, post it as that and you'll get a +1 from me

Comment: And there it was in the photo like that.  How'd I miss that?   Puzzled how the factory could have shipped it that way.  That is bad.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the outlet had the tape over the line side so I was hooking up to the load.  It can be seen in this image if you look at the arrows written in plastic:

[image]

I guess never trust the tape, always check the rest of the writing!